# ConstraintViolationException: Column 'PARENT_ID' cannot be null using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have two classes Parent and Child. Child table has a foreign key which refers primary key of Parent. Here is my hibernate mapping files for both parent and child classes. When I try to save my parent object, I expect both parent and child object present inside parent to be saved. But when I try to save my parent object, I get an exception saying,

> Column 'PARENT_ID' cannot be null

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" 
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false"
    package="com.customer.hibernate.mappings" catalog="customer">
    <class name="Child" table="child_table">
        <id name="childId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="CHILD_ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="childName" type="string">
            <column name="CHILD_NAME" />
        </property>     
        <many-to-one name="parent" class="Parent"
            fetch="select">
            <column name="PARENT_ID"/>
        </many-to-one>      
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false"
    package="com.customer.hibernate.mappings" catalog="customer">
    <class name="PARENT" table="parent_table">
        <id name="parentId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="PARENT_ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="parentName" type="string">
            <column name="PARENT_NAME" />
        </property>     
        <set name="child" cascade="all"
            table="child_table" fetch="select" inverse="false">
            <key>
                <column name="PARENT_ID"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Child"/>
        </set>          
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here are my database tables.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `customer`.`parent_table` 
  ( 
     `PARENT_ID`   INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     `PARENT_NAME` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY(`PARENT_ID`) 
  );  

CREATE TABLE `customer`.`child_table` 
  ( 
     `CHILD_ID`   INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     `CHILD_NAME` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `PARENT_ID`  INT(11) NOT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (`CHILD_ID`), 
     CONSTRAINT `fk_childs_parent_id` FOREIGN KEY (`PARENT_ID`)REFERENCES 
     `customer`.`parent_table` (`PARENT_ID`)ON DELETE no action ON UPDATE no 
     action 
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Andy Ying for your suggestions. The foreign key was not null in the child table. I resolved my issue by adding not-null="true" as below in the parent.hbm.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD   3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false"
package="com.customer.hibernate.mappings" catalog="customer">
<class name="PARENT" table="parent_table">
    <id name="parentId" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="PARENT_ID" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="parentName" type="string">
        <column name="PARENT_NAME" />
    </property>     
    <set name="child" cascade="all"
        table="child_table" fetch="select" inverse="false">
        <key not-null="true">
            <column name="PARENT_ID"/>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="Child"/>
    </set>          
</class>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<many-to-one name="parent" class="Parent" cascade="save-update" fetch="select">
<one-to-many class="Child" inverse="true"/>
```

Comment: I tried this but it persists only the parent object not the child object the reason being inverse="true"

Comment: do you think this method only save parent to table ,but child can not save to table?

Comment: I think,i know your problem. change this `<class name="PARENT" table="parent_table">` to  `<class name="Parent" table="parent_table">`

Comment: You should include an explanation of your answer in order to help readers better understand, and learn.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same as Toni except that the null he adds on the mapping side (hibernate.xml), I did it at the database table level changing my child table Parent_ID as 
from

> `PARENT_ID`  INT(11) NOT NULL,

to

> `PARENT_ID`  INT(11) DEFAUL NULL